# Is it possible to use ansible template/copy on sudoedit granted files

Tags: linux, ansible, privileges, sudoers

I like to use `template` (or `copy`) function in ansible like this:

```
- name: Template a file to /etc/files.conf
  template:
    src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
    dest: /etc/file.conf
```

Problem is, I don't have direct write permissions for remote file `/etc/file.conf`, I can modify it only via `sudoedit`

Is it possible to pipe `template` command through `sudoedit` and modify or copy the file like this?

Comment: I'm curious about your set-up. I've never worked in a place where ansible was used in a meaningful way w/o having elevated privileges ... what user are you connecting as? Why aren't you allowed to "sudo" things?

Comment: And as a thought experiment: you should be able to use the above to create the file from the template in the home of the user, and, assuming e.g. vim as the editor of choice in a subsequent task run sudoedit via the expect module against the original file in `/etc` . Controlling vim via expct `1G;dG;r /home/user/generated_file;:wq`

Comment: @tink, the admin installs the software, I configure the application (it's a cluster with a few dozen hosts). Yes, it would be easier if I (or the admin) could do it all together. But I think this is a never ending dispute between admins and developers.

Comment: Well ... the admin could just give you a single shell script as a target that has the required files hard-coded ... anyway - what do think about the approach above?

Comment: I upvoted and voted to reopen the question. I argue it's `a specific programming problem`. If it is not, why there would be a dedicated section in [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general) to answer exactly this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a workaround for it:

```
# sudoedit.yml

---

- name: Create temp file 
  tempfile:
    suffix: ".{{ sudoedit.suffix }}"
  register: tempfile
  check_mode: no
  changed_when: false

- name: "Check if {{ sudoedit.suffix }} exists"
  stat:
    path: "{{ sudoedit.dest }}"
  register: dest

- name: "Copy content of {{ sudoedit.suffix }} into temp file"
  copy:
    src: "{{ sudoedit.dest }}"
    dest: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
    remote_src: yes
  diff: no
  check_mode: no
  changed_when: false
  when: dest.stat.exists

- name: "Copy file {{ sudoedit.suffix }}"
  copy:
    src : "{{ sudoedit.src }}"
    dest: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
  register: sudoresult

- name: "Modify file {{ sudoedit.suffix }} with sudoedit"
  shell: 
    cmd: sudoedit -n "{{ sudoedit.dest }}"
    stdin: ":%d|:r {{ tempfile.path }}|:1d|:wq"
    executable: /bin/bash
  environment:
    SUDO_EDITOR: /usr/bin/vi
  when: sudoresult.changed
  changed_when: false

- name: Delete the temp file
  file:
    path: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
    state: absent
  changed_when: false
  when: tempfile.path is defined

...
```

Then use it like this:

```
- name: Set NFS exports
  include_tasks: sudoedit.yml
  vars:
    sudoedit:
      src: source/etc/exports
      dest: /etc/exports
      suffix: exports
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"Is it possible to use ansible template/copy on sudoedit granted files? I can modify it only via sudoedit. Is it possible to pipe template command through sudoedit and modify or copy the file like this?"*

A: No. It's not possible. [Privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general) to use `template`, `copy` or any other Ansible module on restricted files with the exception of `command`, `shell` and similar modules that can use `sudoedit` command.

> *"You cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands...."*